# String contains not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to use contains to find out if a phrase appears within a string
The code below works fine in FF and Chrome, however IE8-10 return an error.

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'

```
var str = "This is a string";
if(str.contains("string")){
    alert('Yes'};
}
```

Not sure why IE is throwing a error so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [MDN `String.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) First check documentation, then check Google. Asking someone for help comes later down the line.

Comment: Also your `alert` probably should be `alert('Yes');` not `alert('Yes'};` with a brace.

Answer (score 9):

The `.contains()` function is an ES2015 feature that older Internet Explorer versions don't support.

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) has a polyfill:

```
if ( !String.prototype.contains ) {
    String.prototype.contains = function() {
        return String.prototype.indexOf.apply( this, arguments ) !== -1;
    };
}
```

A general guide for questions like this: type `MDN something` into the Google search box. If you don't find a result, then "something" probably doesn't exist in the JavaScript universe. If you do, then there's a pretty good chance that you'll find the answer you seek there.